# Creating a multi-level list numbered like 1a), 1b)

Tags: lists

I am trying to create a list that will look like this:

1. Something
   1a) apple
   1b) pear
   1c) banana
2. Something
   2a)

This is the code I have now, but apparently it does not automatically change the "1" in "1a)". I have done some searching but did not find what I wanted.

```
\documentclass[10pt, twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{paralist}

\begin{document}
\begin{inparaenum}[\bfseries 1a\upshape)]
    \item
    \item
\end{inparaenum}
\end{document}
```

Thanks

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. You might also want to add to your question how you're including the pdfs etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[**Edit** I realised that using `easylist` is easier than `enumitem`:)]

I am assuming that you want to define an environment `inparaenum` that behaves like this.
The easiest way to do this is (probably) using the [easylist](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/easylist) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[at]{easylist}% easy lists with @ starting each item

\begin{document}

\begin{easylist}
  \ListProperties(Style1*=\bfseries,Numbers2=l,Mark1={},Mark2={)},Indent2=1em)
  @ Something
  @@ apple
  @@ pear
  @@ banana
  @ Something
  @@ Frogs
\end{easylist}

\end{document}
```

This produces the list:

[image]

Another, more standard, alternative is to use the [enumitem](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\newlist{inparaenum}{enumerate}{2}% allow two levels of nesting in an enumerate-like environment
\setlist[inparaenum]{nosep}% compact spacing for all nesting levels
\setlist[inparaenum,1]{label=\bfseries\arabic*.}% labels for top level
\setlist[inparaenum,2]{label=\arabic{inparaenumi}\emph{\alph*})}% labels for second level

\begin{document}

\begin{inparaenum}
  \item Something
  \begin{inparaenum}
    \item apple
    \item pear
    \item banana
  \end{inparaenum}
  \item Something
  \begin{inparaenum}
    \item Frogs
  \end{inparaenum}
\end{inparaenum}

\end{document}
```

This produces the expected list:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

In this case you can easily create what you want using nested environments, you can use the `enumerate` environment for that, but in the inside one instead of use `\item` you can use `\item[1 a)]` for do it in a more explicit way. From your own MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt, twocolumn]{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
    \item Something
    \begin{enumerate}
         \item[1 a)] apple
         \item[1 b)] pear
         \item[1 c)] banana
     \end{enumerate}
    \item Something more
    \begin{enumerate}
         \item[2 a)] watermelon
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Try the code above where you can see the nested environment I told you before. I don't know the environment inparaenum, so probably you forgot to load the package that defines it or you omit the code where you defined it in the preamble.

Anyway, you can also make your own style with the `description` environment or use the `enumitem` package. I'm almost sure that you can find here the answer, this seems not to be the first time I read the question.

Answer (score 1):

A short solution with package `enumitem`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

 \begin{enumerate}

  \item Kisertet
   \begin{enumerate}[label=\theenumi\alph*)]
    \item jarja
    \item be
    \item Europat
   \end{enumerate}

   \item a
   \begin{enumerate}[label=\theenumi\alph*)]
    \item kommunizmus
    \item kisertete.
   \end{enumerate}

 \end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

With `enumitem` you can configure the item labels: `\theenumi` reads out the counter of the highest level, `\alph*` converts the next level counter into a,b,c...